# FSharp POST multiple key/value pairs in F# Data: HTTP Utilities

Tags: f#, f#-data

I understand I should know this right off, but I am so new to F# I am having trouble with the basics. Using the F#: DATA library and the HTTP Utilities. 
They give the example:

```
Http.RequestString("http://httpbin.org/post", body = FormValues ["test", "foo"])
```

The signature of "FormValues" is `seq<string * string>` But that still is not telling me anything yet (due to inexperience). When i used Fiddler to see what happened, the body pair was test=foo. 
So I want to send multiple pairs of key=data values i.e

```
FirstName=Bob
LastName=Smith
Cell=123-456-9876
```

What is the proper syntax to have the multiple pairs for FormValues ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be:

```
[ "FirstName", "Bob" ; "LastName", "Smith" ; "Cell", "123-456-9876"]
```

or

```
[ "FirstName", "Bob"
  "LastName" , "Smith"
  "Cell"     , "123-456-9876"]
```